# new ("") とはなんですか？

Tags: c++

以下のコードにある `memnew` マクロ定義内の `new ("")` とはなんですか？

https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/4.2/core/os/memory.h#L88C1-L94C59

> ```
> template <class T>
> _ALWAYS_INLINE_ T *_post_initialize(T *p_obj) {
>   postinitialize_handler(p_obj);
>   return p_obj;
> }
>
> #define memnew(m_class) _post_initialize(new ("") m_class)
> ```

`memnew` の使用箇所をみるとインスタンス生成のために使用していると推測できます。

https://github.com/godotengine/godot/blob/4.2/main/main.cpp#L547

> ```
> engine = memnew(Engine);
> ```

C++のインスタンス生成には詳しくなく、そもそもJavaなどの言語と違ってC++は new なしでもインスタンスが生成できるようです。

参考：
[C++でクラスをnewしたときとnewしないで使用したときの速度差](https://teratail.com/questions/327338#reply-453200) の回答

上記のマクロも何か new を使用した方が良い場面でかつ何かのテクニックでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

この表現は、C++のプレースメントnew構文を使用しています。通常のnew演算子はメモリを割り当ててオブジェクトを構築しますが、プレースメントnewは特定のメモリ位置にオブジェクトを構築するために使用されます。
プレースメントnewは、既に割り当てられているメモリ領域に直接オブジェクトを構築するために使用されます。

カスタムメモリ管理テクニックは、特定のアプリケーション（例えばゲームエンジンなど）でパフォーマンスやメモリ使用の最適化を図るためにしばしば使用されるようです。

Answer (score 0):

`new ("")` は「placement new」「配置new」と呼ばれるものです。確保済みのメモリアドレス上にインスタンスを配置することによく使われますが、この場合はメモリアドレスを指定しているわけではありません。`new` 演算子には任意の引数を指定することができ(コンストラクタの引数ではない)、この場合は memory.h 69行目の以下の `new` 演算子を呼ぶことになるのでしょう。

```cpp
void *operator new(size_t p_size, const char *p_description); ///< operator new that takes a description and uses MemoryStaticPool
```

この `new` の実装が標準のものと何が違うのか、`p_description` を何に使っているのかは実装のコードを読めばわかると思います。